# Update operation fails "Operation must use an updatable query. (Error 3073)"

Tags: database, ms-access

This is the SQL code, I just don't get the issue.

```sql
UPDATE
    Roster_Master
    INNER JOIN
        DuesCOMP
    ON
        Roster_Master.Scout_ID = DuesCOMP.Scout_ID
SET Roster_Master.Dues     = "Y"
WHERE
    (
        (
            [Roster_Master]![Scout_ID]=[DuesCOMP]![Scout_ID]
        )
    )
;
```

This Idea is simple Table Roster_Master containing a filed called Dues it is set to an "N" at the beginning of each Fiscal year.  As Scout pay their dues this flag needs to be set to "Y" indicates that the Scout has Paid, and the Treasurer need not pursue him/her.

It is obvious to me that this is an UPDATE query, which is based on a data summary Query DuesCOMP.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is what DuesComp SQL code contains.    
 SELECT [Account Transactions].Scout_ID, [Account Transactions].ID, Parameters.FiscalYR, Sum([Account Transactions].Transaction_Amount) AS SumOfTransaction_Amount
FROM [Account Transactions], [Parameters]
GROUP BY [Account Transactions].Scout_ID, [Account Transactions].ID, Parameters.FiscalYR
HAVING ((([Account Transactions].ID)=9) AND ((Sum([Account Transactions].Transaction_Amount))=70))
ORDER BY [Account Transactions].Scout_ID;

Comment: Dear Dick, If you use a "sub query" or "linked text file table" in update query, you will face this issue. To avoid this, your update query must contains just tables (or linked table to excel or access), So you need to reWrite it.

Comment: PLease explain creating a temporary table for this purpose, using my variables??  HELP!

Comment: Don't store this data, just query for it when needed, except you have performance issues. This will ensure up-to-date data. when `Account Transactions` is updated and not only after your update query has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should update a field of table not sub query.

try this:

```
UPDATE 
  Roster_Master INNER JOIN [Account Transactions] 
  ON Roster_Master.Scout_ID = [Account Transactions].Scout_ID 
SET 
  [Account Transactions].Dues = "Y" 
WHERE 
   [Roster_Master].[Scout_ID]=[Account Transactions].[Scout_ID]
  AND
   [Account Transactions].ID=9 
  AND
   Sum([Account Transactions].Transaction_Amount)=70 
;
```

Comment: this is what I typed: **UPDATE Roster_Master INNER JOIN [Account Transactions] ON Roster_Master.Scout_ID = [Account Transactions].Scout_ID SET [Account Transactions].Dues = "Y"
WHERE [Roster_Master].[Scout_ID]=[Account Transactions].[Scout_ID]
  AND
   [Account Transactions].ID=9 
  AND
   Sum([Account Transactions].Transaction_Amount)=70**

Comment: It Failes with: **Cannot have aggregate function in Where claus  ([Roster_Master].[Scouts_ID]=[Account Trasactions].[Scout_ID] And [Account Trasactions].id=9 And Sum([Account Trasactions].[Trasaction_Amount)=70.**   Any Ideas?

Comment: Use having statement for 2 latest conditions.

Comment: Hi, Hamed,  This is exactly what I type as the SQL Statement:  **UPDATE Roster_Master 
INNER JOIN [Account Transactions] ON Roster_Master.Scout_ID = [Account Transactions].Scout_ID 
SET [Account Transactions].Dues = "Y" 
WHERE [Roster_Master].[Scout_ID]=[Account Transactions].[Scout_ID] 
HAVING [Account Transactions].ID=9 AND Sum([Account Transactions].Transaction_Amount)=70;**  Did I do it correctly?  I get the error "Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement. (Error 3137)"   Any Ideas, and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: This will work:
UPDATE 
    Roster_Master INNER JOIN [Account Transactions] 
    ON  Roster_Master.Scout_ID = [Account Transactions].Scout_ID 
SET 
    Roster_Master.Dues = "Y"
where 
    Roster_Master.Scout_ID = ([Account Transactions].[Scout_ID])
    AND
    [Account Transactions].ID IN
        (
            Select ID 
            From [Account Transactions] 
            Group By ID
            Having
              Sum([Account Transactions].Transaction_Amount)=70
              AND 
              [Account Transactions].ID=9
        )
;

Comment: Hi, Hamed, it ran without errors, however, it did not update any records in Roster_Master.  Is there another way we can work on this together?  AND, guess what the users have asked for tracking by Fiscal year, so that adds the condition as they wish to trach other factors by year!!  rpatton@cpsbiz.com

Comment: can you share light version of your database?

Comment: Sure, how do I do that, I will remove most data.  How can I get it to you?

Comment: Just upload to a file sharing website and send its link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-1GKREbtKwGx3fK_SFob7inTv9fwRlux/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As I checked your database, there are 7 records in [account transaction] which their amount are 70, and ID are 9. However In your initial query which you have provided, You typed Sum([Account Transactions].Transaction_Amount)=70 , This means that sum of all records amount that their ID is 9 should be 70. Is it true, or you want to select each record with amount of 70? If the second is true, you should write  [Account Transactions].Transaction_Amount=70.

Comment: The Scouts may make as many payments in a year as necessary to achieve $70.00.  Usually, they will be asked for $35.00 in October and $35 .00 in March.  These funds may come from their "scout account" or paid by parents.  Also, if you check out the Parameters table, the $70.00 is established there as it may vary from year to year.    I had to delete most of the names from the Roster for obvious reasons, but I did leave my name and contact info in there for you.

Comment: Hamed, you should add new names to the BSAS to test using the "Roster Maintenace screen"  only the blue fieds require data and a unique ID.  Then you may pay dues using "Enter Account Transactions" screen and select Dues, category 9.

Comment: Dear Dick, sorry for delay.  No need to add new names, I just  use your provided tables. I think there are some shortages in your given conditions. In account transaction, there are a field "full_name". In your initial conditions it is not used. but according to your previous post, "Maxwell  Buckner" payed 35$ 2 times. So is there need to add that field as another condition? I mean group payments by full_name?

Comment: Or separate by full_name?

Comment: Also [Scout ID]s in roster master and account transactions are not equal.

Comment: Dear Hamed, No problem, and thank you for your help.  There is an error in the database design, it was caused when I unliked the Roster to delete the list of names.  **Please link Scout_id in the roster to Scout_ID in Account transactions.**  The Scout_ID is unique and is the link between the transactions and the person.   If you build a few records and test you will see the issue.